# Sceneform ViewRenderable.Builder.build() crashes App

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, sceneform

I am following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/getting-started) and [this sample](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk.git) for creating a Sceneform application. 
I want to create a widget with `ViewRenderable` & add it to the scene, but the app crashes when `build()` is called.

```
ViewRenderable.builder()
     .setView(this, R.layout.widget)
     .build() // App crashes here!
     .thenAccept(viewRenderable -> {
         ..
     }).exceptionally(
          throwable -> {
               System.out.println(throwable.getStackTrace());
               return null;
          });
```

This is the layout file `widget.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HELLO"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to catch an exception with a `try-catch` block, but the app simply crashes. The only thing I can see in the logcat is this output:

```
2020-04-12 23:41:18.912 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2020-04-12 23:41:18.912 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/CLT-L29/HWCLT:9/HUAWEICLT-L29/9.1.0.387C432:user/release-keys'
2020-04-12 23:41:18.912 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2020-04-12 23:41:18.912 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG: Happend: 'Sun Apr 12 23:41:18 2020
    '
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG: SYSVMTYPE: Art
    APPVMTYPE: Art
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG: pid: 23350, tid: 23350, name: rm.samples.gltf  >>> com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.gltf <<<
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000026e6  x2  0000007c44ae36a0  x3  0000000000000008
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG:     x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000007c60c0e000  x6  0000007c60c15ca0  x7  0000007ce75b05e0
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000007c4457f2f0  x9  0000007c3fc00000  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000000
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000007c60c0e748  x13 0000000000000001  x14 0000007c4457f1e8  x15 ffffffffffffffff
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007ce36f2bd8  x17 0000007ce3686d48  x18 0000007c450e3183  x19 00000000000026e6
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000007c5a252f60  x21 0000007fc0432b58  x22 000000000000c09a  x23 0000000000000000
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000000000000010  x25 0000007ce75b05e0  x26 0000007c60c15ca0  x27 0000000000000004
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000007fc0432c00  x29 0000007fc0432c00
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG:     sp  0000007fc0432af0  lr  0000007c4449949c  pc  0000007c44492108
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2020-04-12 23:41:18.913 23444-23444/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000000092108  /data/app/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.gltf-jNipqK5CUNDrfOaehjPQgQ==/lib/arm64/libgltfio-jni.so
```

Comment: Which version of ARCore Sceneform are you using? v1.16 has an bug raised for this. There seems to be an issue with the Android-filament API.

https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/1025

Comment: I tried it with ARCore v1.16 & v1.15 with Sceneform v1.15, nothing worked for me. I also had problems integrating Sceneform with androidX. I think the libraries included in the sample project are not official. I tried both the included libraries and official ones, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: The crash you see above is easily reproducible on v1.16.  I cannot fathom why it wouldn't work unhindered on v1.15. View Renderables work for me on that version. Care to post an update with what error you see with v1.15?

Comment: Does ViewRenderable not work without ARCore? I've tried creating it inside Sceneform with the same code as my ARCore, but only the ARCore one creates the ViewRenderable